# Creating cross platform applications

Tags: c#, java, cross-platform

I have a fair bit of knowledge of Java and C#.NET (prefer C#).

What should I use to create small applications that will work well in Windows, Mac and Linux? Speed will probably not be the main concern (small applications; using Sockets etc).

Comment: a fair bit of knowledge, but you're not aware of their compatibilities? java's biggest plus is it's cross-platformness, whereas c# is a microsoft technology...and we all know they don't play well with others (although mono does exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Java**

because

1. Java works on Windows,Linux and Mac and even on Mobile phones.(and its official -@cletus)
2. Java has got good **platform independent Sockets Library**.
3. `Eclipse` is great tool for Java Development. (NOTE:you will miss visual studio but not as much)
4. GUI in Java is NOT that BAD.([Example1](http://blog.palantirtech.com/2008/07/04/palantir-screenshots-round-two/#more-95),[Example2](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=119))Thanks @Riduidel.
5. I don't think `mono` is as mature and as good as `.NET`  yet.

Comment: Like the socket library is relevant;) ALL of java is quite decent in a platform independant fashion. As much a C# fan as I am;) Just make sure you can test on all platforms to get around little java quirks here and there.

Comment: @TomTom ;) I suggested java because I don't think `mono` is as mature and as good as `.NET` yet.

Comment: Agreed. I just say pointing out the sockets library makes little sense. ALL of java is platform independant. The sockets libarry is like the smllest part and the easiest.

Comment: I like 'GUI in Java is NOT that BAD' - anything you have to describe like that obviously isn't good. You're correct too - Java will be the least hassle to get working on all platforms.

Comment: GUI in Java are way cooler than you seems to state. There are some really great Swing applications around.

Comment: Without giving application names (as most of them are corproate ones), take a look at this pushing pixel entry : http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=119 or at palantir showcase : http://blog.palantirtech.com/2008/07/04/palantir-screenshots-round-two/#more-95

Answer (score 2):

Both of those are viable options.

Java is officially supported on all three platforms.

C# can be used on Linux and Mac if you're prepared to use the subset of .Net supported by [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Which is more suitable depends on which you're more comfortable with and the exact requirements of the applications you'll be developing.

Answer (score 1):

Java is your best bet. C# and .NET won't work on Mac and Linux without a lot of hoop jumping and headaches. Another option for smaller programs is something like Python.

Comment: As much a C# fan as I am, that is simply true. Just make sure you can test on all platforms to get around little java quirks here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Java is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a server application I would most likely go for Java, but you could also look at Mono for cross platform.

For a desktop application I would try Mono, since I'm mostly a .Net guy. And the desktop apps created in Java are not that appealing graphics wise. Or try to go with SilverLight, but that's not supported as well under Linux (MoonLight).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use C#, try Mono: http://www.mono-project.com